# Online Detect using JavaScript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am writing a web app and I built a script to tell the user they need to be online. I am using JavaScript and JQuery. It does not work. :( This is what I have:

```
var online = navigator.onLine;
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (online == 'false') {
        $('#wifiwarning').fadeToggle("fast");
    };
});
```

Comment: I think `if (online == 'false') {` fails...

Comment: Wouldn't the very definition of 'web app' imply that they are 'on the web'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears [navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine) returns a boolean value, but you are checking for a string.

Instead of:

```
if (online == 'false')
```

you need to use:

```
if (online == false)
```

Comment: thanks @DA. thisly worked perfectly... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think `if (online == 'false') {` condtion fails.

Use

```
var online = navigator.onLine;
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (online) {
        $('#wifiwarning').fadeToggle("fast");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the check in a regular interval like, in your case you are checking the state only once during the page load, any changes to the online state after that is not detected and reacted to.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $el = $('#wifiwarning'),
        visible = $el.is(':visible');
    //execute it every 5 seconds
    setInterval(function () {
        if (navigator.onLine && visible) {
            $el.fadeOut("fast");
            visible = !visible;
        } else if (!navigator.onLine && !visible) {
            $el.fadeIn("fast");
            visible = !visible;
        }
    }, 5000)
});
```

Comment: Any reason this would not be better implemented with `addEventListener` on `online` and `offline` events?

Comment: @Amadan haven't used those before... if you have an idea about it post it as an answer.... then I will delete my answer

Comment: I haven't used them either, I just know they're there (bottom of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine), so it was an honest question thinking you know something I don't that would make it a bad idea.

Comment: @Amadan I just saw it myself... and that is the correct solution to the problem

Comment: @Amadan I think you should post it as an answer :) looks simple enough